# In Android, how to use Google Analytics Event Tracking on button click

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

My goal is to count button click with the use of Google Analytics Event Tracking.

How do I count button clicks and which user (and device) clicked on this button?

I am using this code:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
GoogleAnalyticsTracker tracker;
Button clickBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    tracker = GoogleAnalyticsTracker.getInstance();
    tracker.startNewSession("UA-XXXXXXXX-1", 30, this);
    tracker.setDebug(true);

    clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final Button createEventButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewEventButton);

    createEventButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tracker.trackEvent("Clicks", // Category
                    "Button", // Action
                    "" + clickBtn, // Label
                    77); // Value
            tracker.trackEvent("Clicks", "" + createEventButton, "Easy", 1);
            tracker.trackEvent("Completions", "Game-Deaths",
                    "Hard-Level-One", 15);
            tracker.trackEvent("Die", "Easy", " Two", 15);
            tracker.trackTransactions();
        }
    });

    Button createPageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NewPageButton);
    createPageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Add a Custom Variable to this pageview, with name of "Medium"
            // and value "MobileApp"
            tracker.setCustomVar(1, "Medium", "Mobile App");
            // Track a page view. This is probably the best way to track
            // which parts of your application
            // are being used.
            // E.g.
            // tracker.trackPageView("/help"); //to track someone looking at
            // the help screen.
            // tracker.trackPageView("/level2"); //to track someone reaching
            // level 2 in a game.
            // tracker.trackPageView("/uploadScreen"); //to track someone
            // using an upload screen.
            tracker.trackPageView("/testApplicationHomeScreen");

        }
    });

    Button quitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.QuitButton);
    quitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button dispatchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DispatchButton);
    dispatchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Manually start a dispatch, not needed if the tracker was
            // started with a dispatch
            // interval.
            tracker.dispatch();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Stop the tracker when it is no longer needed.
    tracker.stopSession();
}
}
```

Comment: EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent() method is deprected and EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent() Provide same result.sendEvent is used instead of trackEvent?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In GA console, you can get several numbers. (Engagement -> Events)

Let's explain by example, if you put this line in a button click:

```
tracker.trackEvent("Completions", "Game-Deaths",
                "Hard-Level-One", 15);
```

And user clicked this button twice.

You will get this statistics:

1. Total Event = 2 // 2 clicks
2. Unique Event = 1 // 1 unique source
3. Total Value = 30 // User clicked twice, so 15 + 15 = 30
4. Average Value = 15 // Total value divide by total event

Hope it is clear for you.

Comment: EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent() method is deprected and EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent() Provide same result.sendEvent is used instead of trackEvent?

Comment: Ya, that's correct. -  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events

Answer (score 0):

Please add Google analytics jar file in lib folder.
(copy jar file in lib folder. & project properties -> Java build path -> Libraries -> add jar)
libGoogleAnalytics.jar

jar file link :- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources

I hope solved your problem for adding jar file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the Google Analytics old library ,try using the new V2 library,its easy to use and supported by good documentation. Below is the link for event tracking using the v2 version :https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/events

Comment: Thanks Nargis. I used new V2 library but problem is not solved. Can you send me demo project for counting button click and see result link?

Comment: EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent() method is deprected and EasyTracker.getTracker().sendEvent() Provide same result.sendEvent is used instead of trackEvent?

Answer (score 0):

To send an event to Google Analytics, use `tracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent(...).build())` as shown here - [Event tracking in Google Analytics SDK V3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/events).